# detect when a file opens in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I am extremely new to bash scripting, and I need to create a script that will run a function whenever the user opens a given file (/etc/hosts) with any program.

How can I make my script detect when the file is opened?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Comment: @MarcYoung : Nice finding indeed

Comment: Linux provides the [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) system calls for this sort of stuff, but it's not easily reachable from a shell script....

Comment: @gilez can it be accessed more easily from python scripts?

Comment: @gilez - `inotify-tools` includes `inotifywait` and `inotifywatch` for doing this sort of thing from a shell script.

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon -- if you used the tools TobySpeight suggests above, is could be done from either bash or python. I wasn't aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the the `inotify-tools` package installed (as @TobySpeight mentions in a comment above), then you have the `inotifywait` command available to you, so you can do something like this:

```
while inotifywait -e open /etc/hosts
do
   echo 'hosts was opened!'
done
```

There are lots of options ... [RTFM](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) ... to choose files to watch, etc.

I'm guessing, but I suspect there's a race condition in my code above though. If something opens the file while the script is running the `echo` command, it won't notice, and could miss it while it loops back. Maybe that doesn't matter though.